# Ionic 2: Accessing to the IONIC_ENV always return undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to know how to access to the IONIC_ENV variable so I can choose between use the url of my API in prod or development but when I try to check it, always return undefined.

```
process.env.IONIC_ENV
```

Maybe I need to run or add another configuration but since I'm new with Ionic 2, I don't really know how to do that. I'm trying to access to this variable because I want to publish my app on play store but I have two issues:

1. Angular 2 is always saying is on development mode
2. I cannot access to the ionic_env to decide the final url of my api depending of the environment.

I'm using Ionic2 rc5 and angular-cli to manage the tests with karma/jasmine

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

I assume you are varying between a mobile device and a browser.
All you have to do to tell if its a mobile device is check if windwo.cordova object exists. If it does, use prod url if not use dev url.

Explanation:

IONIC_ENV is a nodejs server variable and you can not access it from your browser since it is the "client".

You could use it in your build process with webpack or ngc but since you are using the ionic app scripts build process you'll either have to fork the build and make your own version or edit the node modules themselves to use this variable. Certaintly not directly in the browser source code.